# Is relative pronoun 'which' missing?

Tags: sentence-structure, relative-pronouns

(1) This has caused a lot of damage to the environment. This damage leads to a loss of biodiversity.

(2) This has caused a lot of damage to the environment, which leads to a loss of biodiversity.

(3) This has caused a lot of damage to the environment, leading to a loss of biodiversity.

Sentence (3) seems to lack the relative pronoun 'which' (compare to (2)). Is (2) supposed to be better than (3), or is (3) correct too?

Answer (score 5):

Your three examples are fine.  On the other hand, adding 'which' to example 3 would be wrong.

https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv106.shtml

> Generally speaking, the participial clause, starting with -ing or -ed, is more characteristic of written English, as it allows us to say the same thing as a relative clause, starting with who, which or that, but with fewer words.

[https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/participle-clauses.html#:~:text=1%3A%20A%20present%20participle%20(verb,is%20a%20friend%20of%20mine)](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/participle-clauses.html#:%7E:text=1%3A%20A%20present%20participle%20(verb,is%20a%20friend%20of%20mine)).

> Participle Clauses
> Reduced Relative Clauses

> We can use participle clauses after a noun in the same way as relative clauses. This gives more information about the noun. We sometimes call this a 'reduced relative clause'.

> The man driving the car is a friend of mine.
> (= The man who is driving the car is a friend of mine).

> We read the email sent by the manager.
> (= We read the email that had been sent by the manager).